# Moved the Apache directory. Now it doesn't work. What should I do?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I am working on Linux (Ubuntu). I've installed apache to `/var/local/` and I've moved the Apache directory to `/usr/local/`. Now it can't start.

I've edited the `httpd.conf` file changing all `/var/local` text to `/usr/local/`. Which other files do I have to change?

Thank you!

Comment: When you say you can't start, what do you mean. And was there a good reason to change the directories? Maybe you could symlink the new locations back to the original and try starting again.

Comment: What's in your apache logs?

Comment: How did you install+move Apache? Are you modifying the version installed from the standard repository by moving files around, or compiling from source?

Comment: Ive downloaded apache from tar, and ./configured ( Where i had mistake writing --prefix=/var/... ) then make and make install 

now i ve looked logs there is no new logs even i try to start apache.
last of all : if i move apache to first place it will start i am sure. But i want it to be start from here where i moved.
Thank you for your concern. I am still need to find solution.
Is there any recommendation ?

Comment: I ve changed everything with gedit where /var there is. But nothing happened. So I ve reinstalling again now. 

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what exactly went wrong, the easiest thing to do would be

1. delete the old install
2. make a fresh one with the right parameters to `./configure`

Is there any reason why you want to compile Apache yourself and not use the package that comes with Ubuntu?

Comment: I ve done what you say at last :) But the biggest reason to try solving this problem is to learn how its working. So i ve preferred to install apache myself instead of ubuntu packages. Thank you. :)

Comment: I really think she is right, what any admin would do would be to run ./configure and again with the proper `prefix` , or maybe just make the symlink as Matt recommended, but I think that would be messier.  If you just want to learn what apache does with this prefix directory to understand it better, I recommend a developers mailing list, irc channel, or maybe just look at the code.